# PSI 2010 ASMX Resource - UpdateResources Error

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, soap, resources, psi

We are trying to use SOAP UI to perform an update request using PSI Resource ASMX Web Services. We are simply performing an update with the same resource dataset information obtained from the ReadResource call.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:res="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/project/server/webservices/Resource/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <res:UpdateResources>
             <res:rds>
               <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
                   <ResourceDataSet xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/project/server/webservices/ResourceDataSet/">
                      <Resources diffgr:id="Resources1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                         <RES_UID>a1d7467d-2a6a-4b0c-b36b-78ef5cbe3fdd</RES_UID>
                         <RES_ID>288</RES_ID>
                         <RES_TYPE>2</RES_TYPE>
                         <RES_HAS_NOTES>false</RES_HAS_NOTES>
                         <RES_CAN_LEVEL>true</RES_CAN_LEVEL>
                         <RES_ACCRUE_AT>3</RES_ACCRUE_AT>
                         <RES_BOOKING_TYPE>0</RES_BOOKING_TYPE>
                         <RES_NAME>Test</RES_NAME>
                         <RES_INITIALS>T</RES_INITIALS>
                         <RES_IS_WINDOWS_USER>false</RES_IS_WINDOWS_USER>
                         <RES_CHECKOUTDATE>2016-02-17T15:36:53.29+00:00</RES_CHECKOUTDATE>
                         <RES_TIMESHEET_MGR_UID>a1d7467d-2a6a-4b0c-b36b-78ef5cbe3fdd</RES_TIMESHEET_MGR_UID>
                         <RES_DEF_ASSN_OWNER>a1d7467d-2a6a-4b0c-b36b-78ef5cbe3fdd</RES_DEF_ASSN_OWNER>
                         <RES_IS_TEAM>false</RES_IS_TEAM>
                         <RES_EXCHANGE_SYNC>false</RES_EXCHANGE_SYNC>
                         <CREATED_DATE>2016-02-15T10:52:25.347+00:00</CREATED_DATE>
                         <MOD_DATE>2016-02-15T10:52:24.673+00:00</MOD_DATE>
                         <RES_STD_RATE_FMT>2</RES_STD_RATE_FMT>
                         <RES_OVT_RATE_FMT>2</RES_OVT_RATE_FMT>
                         <RES_STD_RATE>0.000000</RES_STD_RATE>
                         <RES_OVT_RATE>0.000000</RES_OVT_RATE>
                         <RES_MAX_UNITS>10000.000000</RES_MAX_UNITS>
                         <RES_PREVENT_ADSYNC>false</RES_PREVENT_ADSYNC>
                         <RES_COST_PER_USE>0.000000</RES_COST_PER_USE>
                         <BaseCalendarUniqueId>6578a6ed-4cc2-48e1-84a6-02ac9583d5db</BaseCalendarUniqueId>
                      </Resources>
                      <ResourceRates diffgr:id="ResourceRates1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                         <RES_UID>a1d7467d-2a6a-4b0c-b36b-78ef5cbe3fdd</RES_UID>
                         <RES_RATE_TABLE>0</RES_RATE_TABLE>
                         <RES_STD_RATE>0</RES_STD_RATE>
                         <RES_OVT_RATE>0</RES_OVT_RATE>
                         <RES_COST_PER_USE>0</RES_COST_PER_USE>
                      </ResourceRates>
                      <ResourceAvailabilities diffgr:id="ResourceAvailabilities1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                         <RES_UID>a1d7467d-2a6a-4b0c-b36b-78ef5cbe3fdd</RES_UID>
                         <RES_AVAIL_UNITS>100</RES_AVAIL_UNITS>
                      </ResourceAvailabilities>
                   </ResourceDataSet>
                   </diffgr:diffgram>
             </res:rds>
             <res:validateOnly>true</res:validateOnly>
             <res:autoCheckIn>false</res:autoCheckIn>
          </res:UpdateResources>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I got this response back from the server.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <faultcode>s:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">ProjectServerError(s) LastError=GeneralUnhandledException Instructions: Pass this into PSClientError constructor to access all error information</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <errinfo>
               <general>
                  <class name="An unhandled exception occurred in Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.BusinessLayer.Resource.UpdateResources.">
                     <error id="42" name="GeneralUnhandledException" uid="362c7b0b-6b4f-45c2-9b4a-640623dd7560" Exception="System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.BusinessLayer.Resource.DataSetHasMsxColumns(ResourceDataSet resourceDataSet)
   at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.BusinessLayer.Resource.UpdateResources(ResourceDataSet rds, Boolean validateOnly, Boolean autoCheckIn)
   at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Wcf.Implementation.ResourceImpl.UpdateResources(ResourceDataSet rds, Boolean validateOnly, Boolean autoCheckIn)"/>
                  </class>
               </general>
            </errinfo>
         </detail>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The exception is generic but does anyone know what can be wrong here? the method called has no documentation (DataSetHasMsxColumns) but the name might be suggestive to someone used to work with the services.

Thank you in advance
Best Regards